# How to check JsonNode value is empty or not : java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, object, jsonnode

I want to check Jsonnode value is present or not,
As shown below **myObj** is an input. in this **name** is a key and **""** is a value. I want to check if I get **""** value then it should be go in else part. I tried by using following code but its not working.

```
JsonNode myObj = {name:""};

JsonNode node = myObj.get("name");

if(node != null && !node.isNull()){

// do some things with the item node

} else {

// do something else

}
```

Comment: In java, `JsonNode myObj = {name: ""};` is not a legal statement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
node != null && !node.isNull() && node.textValue().isEmpty()
```